# How to use UITabBar without images... means with text only

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I want to use UITabBar but without images. I want the text to occupy full control space.
i tried setting image to nil, but text is small and aligned to bottom of tabbaritem.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Even I googled alot for the same, still I am not able to do that

It's the default,that text comes @ bottom in Tabbar...

But there is an alternative,as you need to create the *whole tabitem to be as text*

**just use the image with the Text written on it.**

It's Done !!!

Hope this might help me

Comment: This answer is out of date, it is possible. and easy, see my answer

Comment: @meadlai it is right below this one, the function is: [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: aNSDictionaryOfTextAttributes];

Answer (score 20):

This function changes the font of all UITabBarItems:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: aNSDictionaryOfTextAttributes];
```

you can specify the font type and size with a dictionary of attributes similar to those found in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898437/titletextattributes-uiappearance-font-in-ios-7/18906453#18906453).  And then negatively offset the vertical position of the text with this:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -18.0)];
```

Comment: @meadlai could you please downvote the answers claiming it is not possible to try and current-ize this question? thanks

Comment: I had to set the title text attributes for a specific control state. In Swift, this would be, for example: `UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([...], forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Answer (score 1):

Copy this to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -13.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure you can use a UITabBar that way, an alternative would be to use a UIToolbar and have "Custom" UIBarButtonItems with the style set to "Plain".  That would give you a bar without images and have the text occupy the full control space.