# How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 8 embeded with UInavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, ios7-statusbar

iOS8.1(xcode 6.1)
I used the below method to change the status bar text color.

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; }
```

following the link [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called/19513714#19513714)

But this is not working for me.Anyone knows how to change status bar color related to uinavigationcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

1. set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to YES in your info.plist
2. override `- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` in your navigationController. return your childVC
3. override `preferredStatusBarStyle` or something need.

code:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return self.test?UIStatusBarStyleLightContent:UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}

- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    self.test = !self.test;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

let me know if it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the title text style on UINavigationControllers by assigning an NSDictionary containing your settings to the titleTextAttributes property.

```
NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleTextAttributes];
```

More stack overflow discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898437/titletextattributes-uiappearance-font-in-ios-7), and apple ref [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes).