# UINavigationBar.apperance().titleTextAttributes not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

UINavigationBar.apperance().titleTextAttributes not working. Swift Code is below.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

    return true
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18937321/646960

Comment: let attributes:Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: @LoïsDiQual Thank you

Comment: your code is fine it working fine for me, i tested your code

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in Appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
 let navFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 30.0)
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.blackColor(), NSAttributedStringKey.font: navFont!]
```